# Issues with MediaSourceExtension

Tags: javascript, audio, ffmpeg, mp4, web-audio-api

I want to livestream audio only using MSE. I would like to send data/files via websockets, therefore no HLS nor DASH.

But until I implement websockets, I thought to give it a try by statically loading the song in an array.

Here is my code so far:

```
<audio id="ap" controls></audio>
..
<script>
  const ms = new MediaSource();
  var ae = document.getElementById("ap");
  ae.src = URL.createObjectURL(ms);
  ms.addEventListener('sourceopen', msOpen);
  
function msOpen(e) {
  URL.revokeObjectURL(ae.src);
  var mse = e.target;
  const sourceBuffer = mse.addSourceBuffer('audio/mp4');
  var u8A0 = new Uint8Array([0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1C, 0x66, ...]);
  sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(u8A0.buffer);
  
  sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', function() {
    if (!sourceBuffer.updating && mse.readyState === 'open') {
      mse.endOfStream();
      console.log('Audio is ready to play!');
    }
  });
}  
</script>
```

The result is that there are no errors in the debug window and the audio element correctly shows the duration of the song, about two min and half. However, once I click Play, the duration shows 0 (zero) and the song is not played. If I try to pause and play again, the debug window says:

*"Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The fetching process for the media resource was aborted by the user agent at the user's request".
*
This is the ffmpeg command I used to prepare the file:

ffmpeg -i m.wav -c:a aac -b:a 32k -f mp4 output.mp4

Any help would be well appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Is this solved now or you still need an AAC solution? PS: Standard MP4 does not work in MSE. You must use Fragmented-MP4 format if outputting into an MPEG container. It's confusing because both formats are still saved as `.mp4` so you can never know the type until you check/play... To avoid a container, then use MP3 format as a testing format. It does not need to be contained within an MP4 (but AAC does). The MP3 header is also easier to parse (to extract MP3 frame lengths of bytes etc) so it's easier to edit an MP3 on the fly...

Comment: No, it is not solved. Why I need to parse an MP3 header ? Why I need to extract length of bytes ? Why I need to edit an MP3 on the fly ? I thought I would use ffmpeg to split the song in chunks of few seconds each, and then feed them to the MSE 5 - 10 seconds ahead of actual play. Your message as any hint in the right direction is well appreciated.

Comment: It is working with fragmented mp4. I used this ffmpeg command: ffmpeg -i m.wav -c:a aac -b:a 128k -f mp4 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov output1.mp4. Thank you VC.One.